# Index of NSMutableArray not start with 0

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, nsmutablearray

I am trying to add values(MP3 files from document directory) to `NSMutableArray`. I am creating a music player so when a song is finished my method should play next song via `AVAudioPlayer Delegate` . I wrote an `if` statement and checks if the current track is bigger than `array.count` it should play first song which its index is `0`.

The problem is app crashes because of this error : `fatal error: Array index out of range`

Then I print my array and something strange is happening here :

```
print("all files are :\(player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count)")
print("all files  :\(player.MP3DirectoryFiles.description)")
```

> all files are :2
>
> all files  :(" Cake By The Ocean.mp3","LoveSong.mp3" )

It seems counting is OK! there are `2` files but the problem is index of array starts with `0` so in this case `player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count` should be : `1` which means : `0,1`. [IN TABLE VIEW]

I have to say everything works fine in table view to select cell and play songs , but after music is finished that happens.
I need some help to fix this issue here is more code if it helps :

**EDITED 2:**

```
func playMusic(at:Int)  {

        let musicFile = MP3DirectoryFiles[at] as! NSString

        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let musicURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(musicFile.lastPathComponent)

        getDataFromTrack(file: musicURL)

        do {

            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: musicURL)
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.delegate = self
            appDefaults.setTrack(duration: Float(player.duration))


        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error.description)
        }


    }



   func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("musicIsFinished"), object: nil)
    }
```

Another ViewController :

```
  func musicIsFinished(notification:Notification)  {

        _trackRow = appDefaults.loadTrackNumber()


        if _trackRow > player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count {

            _trackRow = 0


        } else {

            _trackRow! += 1

        }

                player.playMusic(at: _trackRow!)
                prepareToPlay()


    }
```

Comment: "`player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count` should be : 1 which means : 0,1", Actually the count should be 2, as the array contains 2 objects.

Comment: @JamesP so what about number of indexes ?

Comment: You probably want `if currentTrack == array.count-1 { //is last track }`

Comment: @JamesP same crash happens ! and is not an standard way  !

Comment: What isn't standard? Show the code that's crashing.

Comment: OK, and is it when you call `playMusic(at:)` that your app crashes? If so...could you show us where you call `playMusic(at:)`?

Comment: @pbodsk please check Edit 2 , `playMusic` is a method in a custom class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so you have two songs in your array.

When you start playing the first song you say...play the song at position 0 (as `NSMutableArrays` are zero based...as you already know :) )

Once the song ends your `musicIsFinished` method is called.

Here you check to see what to play next.

At the moment `_trackRow` is 0 because that is the song you just played and `player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count` is 2.

Your code looks like this:

```
if _trackRow > player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count {
    _trackRow = 0
} else {
    _trackRow! += 1
}
```

So you end up in `else`. `_trackRow` gets incremented and is now 1.

Next you ask to `playSong(at: 1)` and that works (I hope :))

OK...next song is done and we're back at `musicIsFinished`. `_trackRow` is 1 and `player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count` is still 2

So, you check again:

`if _trackRow > player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count`

it is not so `_trackRow` is incremented to 2 and then you ask your array to give you the song at index 2

but...there is no song at index two right? Your array is zero based so you have a song at index 0 and index 1 but not at index 2...so..your app gets confused and crashes.

You need to turn your `if _trackRow > player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count` around and instead ask:

`if _trackRow < player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count - 1`

Meaning that:

The *first* time you enter `musicIsFinished` you end up in the `else` part since

- `_trackRow` is 0
- `player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count - 1` is 1

and 0 is smaller than 1

The *second* time around you end up in the `if` part since

- `_trackRow` is 1
- `player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count - 1` is 1

and 1 is not smaller than 1

Long story I know, but try changing your `musicIsFinished` to this:

```
func musicIsFinished(notification:Notification)  {
    _trackRow = appDefaults.loadTrackNumber()

    if _trackRow < player.MP3DirectoryFiles.count - 1 {
        _trackRow += 1
    } else {
        _trackRow = 0
    }
    player.playMusic(at: _trackRow!)
    prepareToPlay()
}
```

Hope that helps you.